# Optimizing Firebase Documentation for Efficient Reading: Best Practices?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, optimization

I'm currently developing an admin dashboard using Firebase, where I need to fetch data for all members, including their related payments and vehicles.

**Here is the data model I'm working with:**

Overview of data Schema using `typescript` types

```js
export type VehicleDocType = {
  // Vehicle document fields
  owner: string; // Member id
  ...
};

export type PaymentDocType = {
  // Payment document fields
  recipient: string; // Member id
  ...
};

export type MemberDocType = {
  uid: string;
  ...
  /* Note! Arrays are not coming from Firestore and not even part of Schema.
   it is used to map relations on the client side
  */
  payments: Array<PaymentDocType> | null;
  vehicles: Array<VehicleDocType> | null;
};
```

#### Data structure in Firebase

```
----------------------------------------------------------
| Collections |   Documents | Fields                      |
----------------------------------------------------------
| members     |   n docs    | { uid: doc.id, ...}         |
| payments    |   n docs    | { recipient: member.id, ... } |
| vehicles    |   n docs    | { owner: member.id, ... }     |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

[image: Image Reference]

**Note!** `vehicles` collection is the same as `payments`.

---

For the Member page, I want to display all members along with their associated payments and vehicles.

**This is my current approach for data fetching:**

**Firebase SDK:** `"firebase": "^9.22.0"`

> Exact Quries I wanna to make:-

```js
const fetchCustomers = async () => {
  // Fetch member documents from the 'membersCol' collection
  const memberDocs = (await getDocs(membersCol)).docs.map((d) => d.data());

  // Fetch payment documents from the 'paymentsCol' collection
  const paymentDocs = (await getDocs(paymentsCol)).docs.map((d) => d.data());

  // Fetch vehicle documents from the 'vehiclesCol' collection
  const vehicleDocs = (await getDocs(vehiclesCol)).docs.map((d) => d.data());

  
  const members = memberDocs.map((member) => ({
    ...member,
    payments: paymentDocs.filter((p) => p.recipient === member.uid),
    vehicles: vehicleDocs.filter((v) => v.owner === member.uid),
  }));

  // Further processing and rendering of the data
};
```

**While this approach is functional, I have encountered a few problems:**

- Loading large datasets can result in slow data retrieval times.
- When implementing Firebase pagination queries, I'm unsure how to efficiently map the relations (vehicles and payments) to each member.
- I'm looking for best practices to fetch the data with minimal document reads and optimize the overall loading time.

> Any suggestions or recommendations on how to improve the data fetching process, optimize document reads, and reduce loading time would be greatly appreciated. Furthermore, if someone have any recommendations on how to implement real-time updates in this situation.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253880/discussion-on-question-by-zain-ul-din-optimizing-firebase-documentation-for-effi); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had similar issues with our application and were trying to reduce latency and reads.

- If you're using any of the Mobile SDKs the "data bundles" might be a good choice: https://firebase.blog/posts/2021/04/firestore-supports-data-bundles
- Unfortunately setting the "cache" flag was not supported in Node.js, that's why we opted to build our own cache, first by using an in-memory cache. Today we're using Redis to support our backend in handling documents which has resulted in costs and latency dropping by at least 50%.

This could be overkill for your app, so here are some tips on pagination and reducing the amount of reads:

To properly handle pagination you could use an index on your `members` collection if necessary and use `orderBy` to keep the returned items "paginateable".

Now instead of getting all the documents from all collections, just read from the members collection and resolve the payment and vehicle docs as you need them.

```
// Add .startAfter() or other offset parameter to allow pagination here
const members = await firestore.collection('members').limit(10).orderBy('uid').get()
let paymentDocs = []

for (const member of members.docs) {
    const paymentDocs = await firestore.collection('payments').where('recipient', '==', member.data().uid).get()
    paymentDocs.push(paymentDocs[0])
        
    // Do the same for any other fields you need to resolve...
}
```

This is untested pseudo-code and it assumes that there is a  1-1 relationship between members and payment docs.

Comment: I have `vehicles` collection also!

Comment: That what it says in the comment. Just add additional collections when needed.